# Software keeps on asking for admin password however it has been given administrator rights

Tags: administrator

I have TP-Link Wireless USB plugged into my PC at office & have its software installed. While enabling the "Soft Access Point" option on it, it asks for administrator password.

This software has been given full administrator access but whenever I login to my Account & try to switch on the "Soft Access Point option", it still asks for Admin username & Password.

Please tell me whats the problem, or how can this be solved?

Comment: Are you talking about a prompt like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QvHsX.png) ? If you are already have administrator rights then its probably due to UAC setting

Answer (score 0):

You are giving it administrator rights but it still has to request the administrator password to show you are the owner of the account giving it permission to run with admin rights!